# Visual Studio doesn't open a DOS window when I run my Assembly language program with control-F5

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, irvine32

[image: here is my code.]

[image: build succeeded]

I have setup everything. When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, it does not show anything. I just want it to show my name with a black window. How do I do that?

Comment: I believe <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is restart under the Visual Studio debugger. You should only need <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the program under the debugger. If stopped in the debugger (like at a breakpoint) then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> should work for you.

Comment: @jww: No, Ctrl+F5 is "spawn build target without debugging".  If the build target is a console executable, it will also pause after the child process exits, before closing the window.

Comment: it's not a DOS window, it's a cmd or powershell console. [They're different](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). And [don't put images of code or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have the subsystem set to "Windows application", which means the process will start with no console associated.  Attempts to write will then fail.

You can either associate a console with `AttachConsole()` and/or `AllocConsole()` or change the subsystem via linker command line (`/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running your program from within the development environment, open a Command Prompt window and navigate to the folder where the .exe is created and run it directly. That's how command-line programs are meant to be run.

If you *have* to run it in the development environment, perhaps for debugging, then put a breakpoint on the `return` or `exit` statement so it stops before the window is closed.

Comment: +1 for setting a breakpoint instead of adding a crappy hack like a prompt for user input.  Every time I see that in tiny example programs, I always think it would be better to just run your program in a proper environment, or in a terminal set not to close automatically when the program exits.

Comment: "Terminal set not to close immediately when the program ends" is exactly what you get from Ctrl+F5, if the build product is a console app.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've never seen Visual Studio operate that way before. Is that an option you have to set?

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, the command is in the Debug menu after a default install.  Seems completely absent from the Online Help though, because it doesn't exactly fit any of the categories (Build, Debug, Test).

Answer (score 0):

this answer is same as Ben Voigt. i just explain it.
pls check this settings.

I fix this issue by this way.
open project settings << expand Linker << click on "System" << select "**Console(/subsystem:console)**" in subsystem.[image]