# Stopping an assembly program from exiting and closing the console window

Tags: windows, shell, assembly, nasm

```
org 100h
mov dx,msg
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah,4Ch
int 21h
msg db 'Hello, World!',0Dh,0Ah,'$'
```

So, I have this simple "Hello, World!" program in assembly with a `.com` extension. Whenever I run it, the `Hello World!` does display, but it closes the window immediately after, not even after half a second! Is there any possible way to stop the program from exiting until you click the `X` button of the command prompt window?

Comment: `jmp $` will do. It's a (very thigh) never-ending loop. Putting a `xor ah, ah / int 16h` in the loop will also do and is probably better tolerated by the emulator. If you are not limited to the 8086 strictly, the `hlt` or `pause` instructions are more efficient, though this depends on the level of emulation and are probably not worth it.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Hanging a program with an endless loop is a bad practice that I've seen many students learn early. It is better to explain how to set up the development environment properly so that windows stay open when needed rather than teach people to write code that breaks basic assumptions. A basic assumption for a non-interactive console program is that it finishes. The same goes with any kind of `getch()` that blocks indefinitely. Proper exiting techniques, such as calling proper API or (for bare assembler) halting the CPU are more appropriate.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov There is no development environment in the question. Windows hasn't supported 16-bit WOW for a long time now. You are assuming too much. While I agree with you that you have to configure your env, we don't know what the OP is using. Some emulators just flash the output in a window if you don't hang them. The OP already calls the proper API.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Please give me an example of such poorly designed emulator so that I can use it for my students as an example how one must not do. An emulator for dos applications that closes the console immediately, that is something. IDEs, for which such an emulator is simply an external application, are much more likely to behave this way, especially when they mostly are used to start interactive GUI applications, not non interactive stuff.

Comment: It really depends @GrigoryRechistov : For instance if you use DOSEMU on Linux and don't use (or can't) the `-dumb` option and you launch a program like `dosemu progname.exe` the output window will appear, program runs, and will close right away. If you use WINE to run the program from the command line like `wine progname.exe` it will likely launch DOSBOX and open a window, run the program, and close the window right away.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the window closes does not depend on your program, but the environment (e.g. IDE) you use to start it. It is the IDE's settings that should be modified to keep a window for a finished program open until a user explicitly closes it.

It is a bad practice to hang your program with an endless loop at the end just to keep the window open. Such a "hack" creates bad habits. In practice, it breaks common conventions for a non-interactive console program. For example, a hung program cannot be used in automated tests, its output cannot be redirected etc.

A better alternative is to have a separate shell window (CMD.EXE or Powershell, as I suspect you run it in MS Windows) open with current working directory changed to where your program's binary lies. If your file is named `prg.com`, it then can be executed in that window by simply stating its name:

```
c:\dir\> prg.com
Hello, World!
c:\dir\>
```

After execution, the output will stay in the window. Using a command shell, bypassing any IDE, is a essential skill for any assembler program in any case, so I recommend figuring it out early.

Comment: For example, if this is windows, then just run "command prompt" which is a dos console window, then run the test program from there. Note that 64 bit versions of windows can't directly run 16 bit programs, so you'll need something like dosbox or a virtual pc running a 32 bit version of windows or 16 bit msdos.

Comment: This won't work in any 64-bit of Windows (as stated above). The OP may be using an old version of Windows or they may be using an emulator. In that latter case, they may have no alternative but to hang.

Comment: > no alternative but to hang -- other options must be explored before choosing a bad one. HLT is a much better option.

Comment: HLT with a CLI isn't much better than a JMP $

Comment: 100% agreed, the right solution is to configure your dev env once, not to put silly crap in every program you write.  For example, use a terminal emulator that has an option to stay open after the program exits.  e.g.  [`urxvt -hold  -e ./my_prog`], or whatever equivalent on Windows (maybe a Windows port of urxvt; I know Cygwin has an RXVT).

Comment: @PeterCordes I think everyone agrees with that. What I believe is missing is that "configure your env" (which is a very good advice, I repeat) is too general. Considering that the OP is programming for DOS, configuring may or may not possible (usually it is, probably they are running an old Windows). I believe a more careful approach would be to advise to configure your env **and** to show how to hang a program in case a conf is not possible.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: that's reasonable and practical, but my personal opinion is that if your dev env sucks so much that it can't be configured properly, then you should replace your dev env and/or stop using DOS / Windows in the first place if they're that clunky and inconvenient and require silly workarounds.  (I think I'm biased towards keeping a terminal window open and tabbing over to it + up-arrow to run stuff, because that's what I typically do.  That works on Windows.)  Also, forgot to link [the URXVT man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt) last comment.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: A not-too-bad workaround is to [**set a breakpoint at the end of your program** in your IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634923/visual-studio-doesnt-open-a-dos-window-when-i-run-my-assembly-language-program/48635143#48635143). An edit on that post bumped it; I'd forgotten about Mark Ransom's suggestion.